# Type annotation for array destructoring within for-of-loop

Tags: typescript, types

I am currently facing a type issue in typescript:
I want to specify the type of variables in a destructuring assignment inside a *for-of-loop*, in order to be able to add properties to given variable.

However, if I want to specify types like this:

```js
const exampleObject: any = {
    key1: {
        a: "Some value",
        b: 42
    },
    key2: {
        a: "Some other value",
        b: 1337
    }
};
for (const [key, value]: [string, any] of Object.entries(exampleObject)) {
    value.c = 5;
};
```

*eslint* shows me this error:
`The left-hand side of a 'for...of' statement cannot use a type annotation`.

---

Hence, without being able to specify types, I receive this error:
`Object is of type 'unknown'`
on this line: `value.c = 5;`

Am I doing something wrong, or is there any way to annotate types here?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3500#issuecomment-494491530 Looks built into the language and not possible at the moment

Comment: try to declare `exampleObject: { key1: { a: string; b: number; }; key2: { a: string; b: number; }; };`

Comment: @hous Thanks. In my original problem, i am fetching some API related data, so I am not able to specify _key1_, _key2_, etc. since are based on the API's response. Hence, I guess, I am not able to specify the type of exampleObject in this case.

Comment: Are you not able to type the data from your API? Is it giving different results everytime you call it?

Comment: @MikeS. The keys of the nested objects, e.g. _key1_ or _key2_ are representing hashes and are unknown until runtime. They may differ every time the API is called